# How to retroactively add active AJAX request detection to a codebase using YUI asyncRequests

Tags: javascript, html, testing, selenium, yui

We are using the Selenium Web Driver to test a codebase that uses the YUI 2.9 Connection object to make "asyncRequest" (ajax calls). What we would like is a way to detect if there are any active ajax requests using Selenium. Unfortunately, YUI doesn't seem to expose this information. What is then the best way to implement a Jquery like function for detecting active Ajax requests, while keeping in mind that our code base already has over a hundred calls that use the YUI Connection object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set up event handlers for the startEvent, completEvent, and abortEvent events, and subscribe them to the Connection Manager.  When a start event comes in, increment a global counter, when a complete or abort, decrement, then have Selenium wait for the counter to hit 0.